# How to extract shared library version from SONAME field?

Tags: shell, awk, grep, shared-libraries, objdump

There is a shared library say, libsample.so & libsample.so.abc.xy (a,b,c,x and y are 0-9), former having soft link to latter.

How to extract "abc.xy" field from SONAME section of libsample.so?

I have tried below command :
$ objdump -p libsample.so | grep SONAME | awk {' print $2'}
this prints :
libsample.so.abc.xy

But how to further fetch "abc.xy"?

Answer (score 1):

### sed

```
sed 's/.*\.so.//'
```

Test:

```
kent$  sed 's/.*\.so.//' <<<"foo.so.bar.so.so.we.want.this"
we.want.this
```

### awk

```
 awk -F'so[.]' '{print $NF}'
```

Test:

```
kent$  awk -F'so[.]' '{print $NF}' <<<"foo.so.bar.so.so.we.want.this"
we.want.this
```